# What can you currently do with Ubuntu on Nexus 7?

Tags: video, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I am about to buy a Nexus 7 16GB and am wondering if I'll be able to watch videos on it. I know it's a experimental release, but if it can play my movies I'll already be satisfied :)

First thing I'll be doing is removing android for the wonderful Ubuntu :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although ubuntu on nexus 7 has many bug and issues, Play movies is not question.You can play movies by smplayer/vlc software. Play movies is supported.

```
sudo apt-get install smplayer vlc.
```

Comment: Have you tried this on Google/ASUS **Nexus 7** (with Ubuntu-Nexus7 loaded)?  (*Please correct syntax.*)

Answer (score 1):

It's not ready yet, for casual use.

I have experimented with transferring various image and video files to device, but didn't get useful results for video.  *All media files tested worked perfectly on both Android and desktop Ubuntu.*

---

See also: [Installing Ubuntu on the Nexus7 > Known Issues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/KnownIssues)

excerpt:

> - Rotation doesn't work when the tablet is physically rotated
> - Difficult to scroll in Unity
> - No way to right click
> - Suspend from power menu (button press) does not work
> - Webcam doesn't work
> - Bluetooth not yet working
> - Sometimes 'button 1' gets stuck down
> - Shutdown is slow, taking 10-15 seconds
> - Onboard onscreen keyboard doesn't always show when it should
> - On screen keyboard doesn't re-position in order to see input

Comment: David, we have an open bug on videos not working.  Since it sounds like you did some testing would you mind commenting on the bug?  I've not had time yet to try videos.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1072661

Comment: Will look into this further ..

Comment: One can "right click" from the onscreen keyboard as explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/UsingTheDevice